# Atlassian Bamboo cannot read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, bamboo

I am finding a lot of answers to this question, but I am unable to get it to work so far. I am wondering if there are other tools or ways I can use to see where/how I am not getting access. And how I can try to figure out how to get this to work. Also, the firewall is turned off too, so there should be nothing stopping them from connecting.

This is the error I am getting:

ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://bitbucket.ourcompany.org:7999/manage/documents.git", exit code of #128 Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

The strange thing is that I can reference our bitbucket server when creating bamboo build plans, and I have run this command through git bash on our bamboo server and no longer getting any errors. I have created SSH keys and added it to my user account on Bitbucket, and adding it to our bamboo server. I also added them to 'Trusted Sites'.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a problem with the linked repository that  you're using for this plan.  Go to the linked repositories list (admin menu), find and select the repo in question.  If it comes up with an error, re-save it and then re-try your build.  If that doesn't work, I'd take it up with Atlassian support.

Comment: I was able to create this as a linked repository....it is one of the things I tried, I am sorry if I didn't add it to the original message as one of the things I tried.

Comment: No worries - if you select it from the list, does it show any error messages?  If so, then sometimes re-saving it fixes the issue.  Otherwise it's Atlassian support time

Comment: No issues at all...finds it easily...saves it no issue....So I will ask my boss if we have some sort of support account..or do you mean post this on their message boards?

Comment: If you have a current license you have can access web-based support @ https://support.atlassian.com/